# R dplyr::case_when - syntax when having alternative true-values for condition of one case

Tags: r, dplyr, case

Might be a very basic question. However (maybe as I am quite new to R) I could not find a smarter solution for my little issue with `case_when`. 
If I have more than one value that matches the condition of ONE case to be true, one option is the following syntax:

```
> testnr <- 1
> print(case_when(testnr == 2 | testnr == 3 | testnr == 7 | testnr == 9  ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
[1] "false"
> print(case_when(testnr == 1 | testnr == 3 | testnr == 7 | testnr == 9  ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
[1] "true"
```

So far, so good. But, especcially when having some more 'true'-values (instead of just four as in my example), code is gonna be very long. So, I'm looking for shorter way in the sense of `if testnr == 2 or 3 or ...` without repeating  `testnr ==` between each `|`
Here some of my 'genius' ideas which all went wrong:

```
> print(case_when(testnr == 2 | 3  | 7  | 9 ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
[1] "true"
> print(case_when(testnr == (2 | 3  | 7  | 9) ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
[1] "true"
> print(case_when(testnr == c(2 | 3  | 7  | 9) ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
[1] "true"
> print(case_when(testnr == c(2,3,7,9) ~ "true", TRUE ~ "false"))
[1] "false" "false" "false" "false"
```

Any body an idea for me?
And in case there should not be any smarter alternative I would also be glad if somebody would confirm that.

Comment: You can use the `%in%` statement. `...testnr %in% c(2,3,7,9) ~ "true"...`

Comment: I was quite sure that should not be a big deal, but couldn't find the right post at the very moment ... Thanks and have a nice day!